# GherkinScenarioFactory not execute any test case

Tags: cucumber-jvm, gherkin, cucumber-java, qaf

I use cucumber testNG for my project and and already added some configuration based on [Configuring BDD for execution](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/bdd-configuration.html) and [QAF Cucumber](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-cucumber) but when i run it, GherkinScenarioFactory not run any test.

```
[main] ERROR com.qmetry.qaf.automation.util.PropertyUtil - resources\application.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)
[main] INFO com.qmetry.qaf.automation.core.ConfigurationManager - ISFW build info: {qaf-Type=core, qaf-Revision=15, qaf-Version=2.1, qaf-Build-Time=20-N
ov-2019 22:28:06}
[main] ERROR com.qmetry.qaf.automation.core.ConfigurationManager - D:\Automation\resources not exist!
include groups []
 exclude groups: [] Scanarios location: resources/features
[main] INFO com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.gherkin.GherkinScenarioFactory - scenario.file.loc[Ljava.lang.String;@400cff1a
[main] INFO com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.gherkin.GherkinScenarioFactory - total test found: 0
```

I've added the dependency **qaf** and also **qaf-cucumber** with version **2.1.15**. I've also added the **@QAFTestStepProvider** annotation in the step file. Here's my testng.xml file :

```
<suite name="MyTest">
<test name="ComparationTest" >
    <parameter name="step.provider.pkg" value="com.example.steps" />
    <parameter name="scenario.file.loc" value="resources/features" />
    <classes>
        <class name="com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.gherkin.GherkinScenarioFactory" />
    </classes>
</test>
```

in the feature file I added : **Examples: {'datafile': 'resources/data/data.xls'}**
and last in cucumber runner I added plugin "com.qmetry.qaf.automation.cucumber.QAFCucumberPlugin"

I'm still learing, can somebody tell me what did i miss?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It looks that you are pointing to wrong location for resources and feature file/directory. You need to provide **relative path to project root directory** for resources and scenarios directory. If you observe the log also complains that fie/folder not exist.

```
[main] ERROR com.qmetry.qaf.automation.util.PropertyUtil - resources\application.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)
[main] INFO com.qmetry.qaf.automation.core.ConfigurationManager - ISFW build info: {qaf-Type=core, qaf-Revision=15, qaf-Version=2.1, qaf-Build-Time=20-N
ov-2019 22:28:06}
[main] ERROR com.qmetry.qaf.automation.core.ConfigurationManager - D:\Automation\resources not exist!
```

Make sure that you have resources directory under project root.

Regarding feature files, according to your current configuration
`scenario.file.loc` is `resources/features`. In that case make sure that `<project-root>/resources/features` is exist. For example your project root is `D:/Automation` then `resources/features` points to  `D:/Automation//resources/features`
If not then provide correct relative path to project root.

For example `resources/features` expects `<project-root>/resources/features` if it is not there provide correct location.

Same is applied for other resources including properties file and test data files.

For `application.properties` it is expected under `<project_root>\resources\application.properties` if it is not there you can provide location by using system property `application.properties=<relateive_path_to_project>` or alternately place under default location  `<project_root>\resources`.

As a side note,

- instead of `GherkinScenarioFactory` recommended is [BDD2](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/bdd2.html) factory `com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.text.BDDTestFactory2`
- Latest version of qaf as of today is `3.1.0-RC1` the version you are using `2.1.15` is quite old.